# CS1301xl Computing in Python I practice exam mortgage problem’s formula may be somehow incorrect?

Tags: python, edx

I’d like to know whether this is the formula problem or my problem.

I’ve looked up various formulas online. This is edx’s formula 
Cost * Number of Months * Monthly Rate / 1 - ((1 + Monthly Rate) ** Number of Months)

```
cost = 150000
rate = 0.0415 
years = 15
rate = rate / 12 
years = years * 12
house_value = cost * years * rate 
house_value2 = (1 + rate) ** years
house_value = house_value / house_value2
house_value = round(house_value, 2)
print("The total cost of the house will be $" + str(house_value))
```

It should print “The total cost of the house will be $201751.36” but it prints “The total cost of the house will be $50158.98”

Comment: Can you link to the edx's formula please?

Comment: If you have an edx account you can view this. https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:GTx+CS1301xI+1T2019/courseware/61e71a3780d34bc79f8a0fed16457d3c/8adc3f7e00bb490d9666134a9f9af941/

Comment: I do not. Is the rate the yearly rate or the monthly rate?

Comment: At first it is yearly but then I added “rate = rate / 12” so in the code it is monthly

Comment: Ah I see that now. Given your formula, your code is correct.

Comment: So the formula is wrong?

Comment: According to the formula, you do 1 - in the denominator, but you don't have that in your code. However, that changes the whole denominator to negative, which gives an undesirable result. If the course is using that formula, then I'd message the instructor about how they came to the final number.

Comment: I have reported this is in the edx community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this. This is the edit.

```
cost = 150000
rate = 0.0415 
years = 15
house_value = cost * (years * 12) * (rate / 12)
house_value2 = 1 - (1 + (rate / 12)) ** -years
house_value = house_value / house_value2
house_value = round(house_value, 2)
print("The total cost of the house will be $" + str(house_value))
```

I have added a negative sign to the years.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix the formula.

Comment: Actually there was a bug but then I removed the years * 12 and rate / 12. I had to manually do that later in the code but, it’s now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Going off your answer with the correct formula, you can simplify the code quite a bit and add more readability by doing the following:

```
# This is a function that lets you calculate the real mortgage cost over
# and over again given different inputs.
def calculate_mortgage_cost(cost, rate, years):
    # converts the yearly rate to a monthly rate
    monthly_rate = rate / 12
    # converts the years to months
    months = years * 12
    # creates the numerator to the equation
    numerator = cost * months * monthly_rate
    # creates the denominator to the equation
    denominator = 1 - (1 + monthly_rate) ** -months
    #returns the calculated amount
    return numerator / denominator


# sets the calculated amount
house_value = calculate_mortgage_cost(150000, 0.0415, 15)

# This print statement utilizes f strings, which let you format the code
# directly in the print statement and make rounding and conversion
# unnecessary. You have the variable inside the curly braces {}, and then 
# after the colon : the comma , adds the comma to the number and the .2f
# ensures only two places after the decimal get printed.
print(f"The total cost of the house will be ${house_value:,.2f}")
```

Comment: Thx but actually, the auto grader changes the values so this would not work.

Comment: What does the auto grader require?

Comment: Basically it changes the variables and if there are no wrong answers it marks correct